# AJAX if JSON-response = X -> do action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on a site and now I am at the point that I have to make the AJAX-forms. The code I have now does insert the params in the database, but now I get stuck at the following point. I want my code to hide the form after the status of JSON is success. Working in a MVC. This is my code:
(I have let the unimportant part of the code away)
AJAX:

```
$("#submitAssignment").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/set/new/ass",
        async: true,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Het item is toegevoegd");
            var err = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            sendAlert.createAlert(err.return, err.type);
            if (jsonObj.status == 'success') {
                $("#submitAssignment").hide();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
else {
    $UserModel = new UserModel();
    if ($UserModel->placeAssignment($title, $uploadable, $level, $points, $description)) {
        $err['data'] = array("status" => "success", "type" => "success", "return" => "De opdracht is toegevoegd! Joepie :D" );
    } else {
        $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "type" => "danger", "return" => "Er is iets misgegaan!");
    }
}
exit( $err['endpoint'] = json_encode( $err['data'], $options = 0 ) );
```

The part I want to hide after status = succes, does not hide, so thats my problem. I have searched other questions, but aint got success with that. What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: Where is `jsonObj` set?

Comment: i think you were meaning to look at `err.status` rather than `jsonObj.status`

Comment: did you debug the code to see if there are any errors or did the code reach inside if condition, err is never used

Comment: Well there you go @TimothyGroote . That was the problem. Now it does work :)

Comment: @WillemDN you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case is that I used the wrong call-back in the ajax-code. I used JSONobj.status, but it need to be: err.status because I am handling it at that way. @timothyGroote gave this answer and now it works. 
My ajax-code now:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/set/new/ass",
        async: true,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Het item is toegevoegd");
            var err = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            sendAlert.createAlert(err.return, err.type);
            if (err.status == 'success') {
                $("#submitAssignment").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please don't use "return" as an object. its a keyword of Js.